# Is there any Operating System that do not support threading?

Tags: multithreading, operating-system

Is there any Operating System that do not support threading?

I read somewhere CLI threading will not work on OS that do support threading, was just curious which are such OS??

Comment: If you call `MSDOS` an O.S., it does not support threading. And old Unix systems (like SunOS3 in the 1980s) did not have threads, only processes.

Comment: CP/M did not support threading until MP/M, (I'm feeling old today..:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MS-DOS does not support threading.

Answer (score 1):

Mac OS 9, Windows 3.1 do not have threads.